# CheckComboBoxColumn in DevExpress GridView

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I want to get CheckedList DropDown control, which is a basic DropDown with checkbox in front of each list item.

I found [this demo](http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxeditorsdemos/ASPxDropDownEdit/CheckComboBox.aspx) from their official site but I want the same effect in a ASPxGridView column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand your question clearly. Do you want to use `CheckComboBoxColumn` in `ASPxGridview` Column ? If so, you can use it like this.

```
    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid" ClientInstanceName="grid" runat="server"
.........................
<Columns>
.........................
<EditItemTemplate> // If your Gridview has Edit Property. 
.........................
<dx:ASPxListBox ...
```

If that didn't what you want, please let me know.

**NOTE**: Did you look `ASPxGridLookup` control ? [GridLookup - Multiple Selection](http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/ASPxGridLookup/MultiSelect.aspx)

**EDIT1**: Check the following code.  [How to implement a CheckComboBox editor in the ASPxGridView](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E2250.aspx?searchtext=CheckComboBox%20%20aspxgridview)

**.ASPX**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register
Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v9.3, Version=9.3.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"
    Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView" TagPrefix="dx" %>
<%@ Register
Assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v9.3, Version=9.3.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"
    Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors" TagPrefix="dx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>GridCheckComboBox Emulation</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var textSeparator = ",";

        function OnGridSelectionChanged(Grid, args, checkComboBox) {
            UpdateText(Grid, checkComboBox);
        }
        var _checkComboBox;
        function UpdateText(checkGrid, checkComboBox) {
            _checkComboBox = checkComboBox;
            checkGrid.GetSelectedFieldValues('CategoryID;CategoryName', OnGetSelectedFieldValues);
        }
        function OnGetSelectedFieldValues(items) {
            var texts = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
                texts.push(items[i][0]);
            texts.join(textSeparator);
            _checkComboBox.SetText(texts);
        }

        function SynchronizeGridValues(dropDown, args, checkGrid) {
            var values = dropDown.GetText().split(textSeparator); 
            checkGrid.UnselectAllRowsOnPage();
            checkGrid.SelectRowsByKey(values);
            //UpdateText(checkGrid, dropDown);  // for remove non-existing texts
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
                <Columns>
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CategoryID" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="0">
                        <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="test" VisibleIndex="1">
                        <DataItemTemplate>
                            <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
                                <Columns>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CategoryID" ReadOnly="True"
VisibleIndex="0">
                                        <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="test" VisibleIndex="1">
                                        <DataItemTemplate>
                                            <dx:ASPxDropDownEdit ID="ddE" runat="server" OnInit="ddE_Init">
                                                <DropDownWindowTemplate>
                                                    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid" runat="server"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="CategoryID"
                                                        DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1"
SettingsBehavior-AllowMultiSelection="True"
                                                        OnInit="grid_Init">
                                                        <Columns>
                                                            <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowSelectCheckbox="True"
VisibleIndex="0">
                                                            </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                                                            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CategoryID"
VisibleIndex="1">
                                                            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                                            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="CategoryName"
VisibleIndex="2">
                                                            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                                        </Columns>
                                                        <SettingsPager Mode="ShowAllRecords" />
                                                    </dx:ASPxGridView>
                                                    <table style="width: 100%"><tr><td align="right">
                                                        <dx:ASPxButton ID="btn" runat="server" Text="close"
AutoPostBack="false" OnInit="btn_Init">
                                                        </dx:ASPxButton>
                                                    </td></tr></table>
                                                </DropDownWindowTemplate>
                                            </dx:ASPxDropDownEdit>
                                        </DataItemTemplate>
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                                </Columns>
                                <SettingsPager Mode="ShowAllRecords" />
                            </dx:ASPxGridView>
                        </DataItemTemplate>
                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                </Columns>
                <SettingsPager Mode="ShowAllRecords" />
            </dx:ASPxGridView>
            <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/nwind.mdb"
                SelectCommand="SELECT [CategoryID], [CategoryName] FROM [Categories]"></asp:AccessDataSource>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**.CS**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors;
using DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void ddE_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ASPxDropDownEdit dropdownedit = sender as ASPxDropDownEdit;
        ASPxGridView grid = dropdownedit.NamingContainer.NamingContainer as ASPxGridView;

        string key = grid.UniqueID;
        string visibleIndex = (dropdownedit.NamingContainer as GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer).VisibleIndex +
key;
        dropdownedit.ClientInstanceName = "dde" + visibleIndex;

        dropdownedit.ClientSideEvents.DropDown =
            String.Format("function(s,e) {{ SynchronizeGridValues(s, e, grid{0});}}", visibleIndex);

        dropdownedit.ClientSideEvents.TextChanged =
            String.Format("function(s,e) {{SynchronizeGridValues(s, e, grid{0});}}", visibleIndex);   
    }
    protected void btn_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ASPxButton button = sender as ASPxButton;
        ASPxGridView grid = button.NamingContainer.NamingContainer.NamingContainer.NamingContainer.NamingContainer
as ASPxGridView;

        string key = grid.UniqueID;
        string visibleIndex = (button.NamingContainer.NamingContainer.NamingContainer.NamingContainer as
GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer).VisibleIndex + key;

        button.ClientSideEvents.Click = String.Format("function(s, e){{dde{0}.HideDropDown();}}", visibleIndex);
    }
    protected void grid_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ASPxGridView curGrid = sender as ASPxGridView;
        ASPxGridView grid = curGrid.NamingContainer.NamingContainer.NamingContainer.NamingContainer.NamingContainer
as ASPxGridView;

        string key = grid.UniqueID;
        string visibleIndex = (curGrid.NamingContainer.NamingContainer.NamingContainer.NamingContainer as
GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer).VisibleIndex + key;
        curGrid.ClientInstanceName = "grid" + visibleIndex;

        curGrid.ClientSideEvents.SelectionChanged =
            String.Format("function(s,e) {{ OnGridSelectionChanged(s, e, dde{0});}}", visibleIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I want to have a CheckComboBoxColumn in ASPxGridView column, I have some confusion adding markup code from the demo I posted the link to, please can you guide me how to merge that code with GridView markup code and post the merging result? thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please let me know If that isn't what you want.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it and see, but really? 3 nested grid views?